# Profile Activity Data settings are unclear

Tags: feature-request, status-review, profile-page, personal-data

Currently when you view your activity data settings you're presented with this information and a button:

> ###### Stack Overflow never sells or shares your activity data with third parties.
>
> We use your on-site activity to show you more relevant content. For example, we might show you questions based on the tags you usually browse, or show you job listings in your current location.

> ###### Use my on-site activity to show more relevant content (recommended)
>
> If you opt-out, existing recommendations will be discarded within 24 hours.

What all is this information actually used for now? In what scenarios is it used to determine which ads we see? Shouldn't this explanation be updated to more accurately reflect that it may be used to determine which 3rd party ads we are shown if it is going to be used for more than the companies feature?

Currently it is somewhat unclear what exactly would be disabled if we decided to opt out. I'd imagine most people probably don't realize that "For example, we might show you questions based on the tags you usually browse" only applies to the home page (assuming that's still the case... of course.)

Put another way, if I were to disable this, would my homepage question list become a mess of random questions rather than the neatly curated list of questions that I get now? That’s quite a bit more significant than the text seems to indicate.

[image: Activity Data preferences]